# Flink - kafka connector OAUTHBEARER Class loader issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, jaas, sasl

I try to configure kafka authentification using sasl mechanism (OAUTHBEARER)(using flink 1.9.2, kafka-client 2.2.0).

When using Flink with SASL authentification I got the exception bellow.
Kafka is shaded in a fat jar with the application.

After a remote debugging I found that my callback handler has a `ChildFirstClassloader` and
org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.AuthenticateCallbackHandler belongs to another  `ChildFirstClassloader` so the `instance of` the following test is failing (`OAuthBearerSaslClientFactory`) :

```
if (!(Objects.requireNonNull(callbackHandler) instanceof AuthenticateCallbackHandler))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
         "Callback handler must be castable to %s: %s",
         AuthenticateCallbackHandler.class.getName(), callbackHandler.getClass().getName()));
```

I have no idea why these two classes have two different classloader.

Any idea? Any workaround?

Thanks for the help.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Callback handler must be castable to org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.AuthenticateCallbackHandler: org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.OAuthBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.OAuthBearerSaslClient$OAuthBearerSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(OAuthBearerSaslClient.java:182)
    at javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:420)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.lambda$createSaslClient$0(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:180)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.<init>(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildClientAuthenticator(SaslChannelBuilder.java:254)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.lambda$buildChannel$1(SaslChannelBuilder.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.<init>(KafkaChannel.java:140)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:210)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.buildAndAttachKafkaChannel(Selector.java:334)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.registerChannel(Selector.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:257)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:920)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:287)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.trySend(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:474)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:255)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.getTopicMetadata(Fetcher.java:292)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(KafkaConsumer.java:1803)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(KafkaConsumer.java:1771)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaPartitionDiscoverer.getAllPartitionsForTopics(KafkaPartitionDiscoverer.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractPartitionDiscoverer.discoverPartitions(AbstractPartitionDiscoverer.java:131)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.open(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:508)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:552)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:416)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Hey @YoelBen did you ever get an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've solved this already, but I wrestled with this exact same scenario for quite a while. What ended up working for me was copying the kafka-clients jar into Flink's lib/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry forgot to post the solution, but yes i solved it in the same way, by copying the kafka-client in flink lib.

Comment: what were the steps taken to copy the kafka-client in the Flink opt/flink/lib? I.e. did you have to download and copy it in your Dockerfile and exclude it in maven dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exact issue and struggled with it for many weeks. In my case, just dropping the `kafka-client` jar into my `/opt/flink/lib` directory wasn't enough. This is because the issue that caused this wasn't simply a `kafka-client` library issue.

**Classloading**:

First, if you are unfamiliar with class-loading in Java, I implore you to look  into that concept. You will not be able to understand any answers without that knowledge.

**Issue Cause Overview**:

The root cause of this issue is how Flink loads classes in your project (this will also vary based on deployment mode (session or application)). If you are deploying via application mode, you are uploading your jar file into the `userlib` folder.

1. When the `jobmanager` starts, it will read your code via it's classloaders, create a job graph, do optimizations, etc.
2. Then it ships the code needed in each part of the job graph over the network so that your `taskmanagers` can run it.
3. The `taskmanagers` pick up this code, load it with the `UserCodeClassLoader`, and execute your application.

If all goes well, then your application runs successfully. However, this issue appears in the failure case. So what's happening? Flink's `UserCodeClassLoader` is a child first class loader. What does this mean? Well the normal process of loading classes in a java application is parent first. So if a child classloader needs a class, then it asks the parent if it has already loaded it, and if it has, it will use this. However, Flink does things a little differently. The `UserCodeClassLoader` is a child-first class loader, which means that if a classloader is missing a dependency, it'll ask it's children first. Flink made this choice because it means that dependencies of the Flink cluster (also written in java), will not conflict with any dependencies you import.

So, this error, an instance of error in my case, tells us that the class was loaded by 2 different classloaders. An `instanceof` check will fail (even if it's the same class), if it is loaded by 2 different classloaders.

**Solution**:

1. Create a separate uber jar with just your dependencies - you can use the maven shade plugin with the `createDependencyReducedPom` option set to `false`. If you are using the avro generation plugin to create a java object from schema, you may also need to add that in there too. You'll put `kafka-client` in this jar, too.
2. Remove any uber jar config you might have had in your original project. You don't want to bundle dependencies as they will be loaded by the child-first classloader.
3. Add your uber jar to your `opt/flink/lib` folder so that it gets loaded by Flink's parent classloaders and is available and loaded only once.
4. If you need any libs (i.e. avro schema generation objects), add the new uber jar as an import in your maven project.

This solution avoids having to worry about which classes are loaded by which child classloaders.